# How to test javascript chaincode in Fabric 2.3 Dev mode?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I want to test my javascript chaincode in Fabric 2.3 DEV mode.
But i don't known how to install the javascript chaincode, the Docs only has the Go simple.
Can you help me?

[image: Screenshot of tutorial]

Answer (score 0):

I got it successfully working using javascript chaincode using the following:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network

Of importance is:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network/scripts/deployCC.sh

You can look in this script for the details on what is happening.

To invoke this script with a javascript chaincode, use the following command:

```
./scripts/deployCC.sh -c edb -ccn ts -ccp <your_chaincode-ts_path> -ccl typescript
```